# Handling Buffer sent from Express to React to download an image

Tags: reactjs, express, download, attachment, content-disposition

I am trying to download an image from my s3 server. I successfully grab the file no problem in my express server as a Buffer. I then pipe it to the client and log it which results in the large binary file. The download in the browser shows up as well but it fails because it says there is no file. How do you get it to download the Buffer file that it sent as an attachment and have it save on the person's computer (either automatically in Downloads or allow people to choose what to use). I am using React js.

When it fails to download anything, in the download section on chrome, it will say `Downloads Failed - No file`

server

```
app.post('/download', (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.id) {
    User.findById(req.body.id)
    .then(user => {
      user.Images.filter(e => e.key === req.body.Images.key)
      .forEach(file => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', file.mimetype);
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${file.originalname}`);
        res.setHeader('Content-Length', file.size)
        s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'bucket-name', Key: file.bucketKey })
        .createReadStream()
        .pipe(res)
      })
    })
    .catch(err => res.json({message: 'No user could be found.', err}));
  } else { res.json({message: 'You must be logged in to download these files.'}); };
});
```

client download button

```
<Button onClick={this.download} href='~/Downloads' download>Download Image</Button>
```

action

```
export const imageDownload = image => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/image-download', image)
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.data.message) {
        console.log(res.data);
        return dispatch({ type: 'DOWNLOAD', Download: res.data});
      } else { console.log(res.data); };
    })
    .catch(err => { console.log(err); });
  }
}
```

`res.data` is a massive binary/buffer/encode file like `` �<�˹���v���5�`���|�=�� `` but much longer. This means that I must have gotten the file however it does not download.I am also uncertain if the redux call is even necessary.

Edit: I no longer have access to this codebase so I cannot test it but I believe that the solution would be

```
    app.post('/download', (req, res) => {
      if (req.body.id) {
        User.findById(req.body.id)
        .then(user => {
          user.Images.filter(e => e.key === req.body.Images.key)
          .forEach(async file => {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', file.mimetype);
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${file.originalname}`);
            res.setHeader('Content-Length', file.size)
            const file = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'bucket-name', Key: file.bucketKey })
            fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(res)
          })
        })
        .catch(err => res.json({message: 'No user could be found.', err}));
      } else { res.json({message: 'You must be logged in to download these files.'}); };
    });
```

Comment: I'm stuck here as well. Did you find and answer?